# Best way to pass messages between 2 different protocol routes connected to same client

Tags: go, server, client, server-sent-events

I have a http route `/checkout` which initiates a workflow process in Zeebe. The `checkout` route will return `200` response straight-away to calling client. Now, workflow will run for a while. So to push the response back to client after completion, I have a `/sse` separate route for *server-sent events*. Here, I will store all the client connection in a global `map`.

My doubt is how do I find the exact client to send the response back through `sse` once?

- Example: Client **A** listening to `/sse` and calls `/checkout` endpoint which will return 200. The `/sse` has to return the response to client **A** after completion.

Currently, I thought of using cookie to identify the client. Is there a better way?

Comment: Cookie or. a simple unique header value should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using cookies in your app than that's the way to go since the very purpose of cookies is identifying the client, so if you already have that, you should use it.

But if you rely on another authentication mechanism (like JWT), what you could do is using the url as a query.

So in the client instead of

`let eventSource = new EventSource("/sse");`

Do

`let eventSource = new EventSource("/sse?authorization=jwt_token");`

In the backend, you would validate that token, extract the Client ID and hit that global map with it to retrieve the corresponding connection.

(PS: instead of a global map, you should use a proper store, like redis, or an embedded key/value store like [bbolt](https://github.com/etcd-io/bbolt))